# Decoding UTF-16 with CRLF line endings from a line-based iterator

Tags: perl, unicode

So, I have an iterator object that returns lines, which are later decoded as the iterator doesn't know about encodings. All fine, right up until I tried to add UTF-16 support.

Here's roughly my code:

```
use Encode qw(decode);
my @lines;
my $buffer = '';
while($buffer .= $iter->next){
    push @lines, decode("UTF-16LE", $buffer, Encode::FB_QUIET);
}
```

The data is little-endian UTF-16 with CRLF line-endings. Here's the first line pumped through `od -a`:

```
0000000   ff  fe   e nul   m nul   a nul   i nul   l nul  ht nul   l nul
0000020    a nul   n nul   g nul   u nul   a nul   g nul   e nul  ht nul
0000040    e nul   x nul   a nul   m nul   p nul   l nul   e nul   _ nul
0000060    t nul   e nul   x nul   t nul  cr nul  nl nul
```

The problem that I've got is that I end up with the line endings split. The first line ends in a CR, and the second begins in an LF, and so on.

Any idea what's going on here and how to get around it?

Edit:

On closer inspection, what's happening is the line-based iterator is returning everything up to and including the LF, but (importantly) NOT the null byte after it. `decode()` is set up to only read the characters it can from the buffer, so leaves the lone LF in the buffer for next time. The next iteration comes around and adds everything up to the next LF, which includes the null. So you end up with a CR at the end of one line and a LF at the beginning of the next.

I'm not really sure what to do about that, apart from have another buffer on top that reads only complete lines from `decode()`s output..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens when you try to read UTF-16 with code that expects ASCII.  With ASCII-compatible encodings like ISO 8859-1 and UTF-8 you can read them with code expecting plain ASCII (as long as it's 8-bit clean) and then decode them later.  That just doesn't work with UTF-16.  UTF-16LE is worse, because the LF is represented as `0A00`, but similar problems can crop up with big-endian also.

What happens when your file contains [U+010A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/010a/index.htm)?  Or [U+020A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/020a/index.htm)?  Or [U+0A01](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0a01/index.htm)? Or ...

You're going to have to teach your iterators about encodings, or insert a layer below the iterator to do decoding, or write an iterator that reads "lines" from another iterator and assembles them into properly decoded actual lines.

Comment: Yep, thanks, rapidly coming to that conclusion! I think what should really be happening is these iterators should deal with blocks rather than lines, until the contents has been decoded. At which point we can convert to lines if necessary. Has the advantage of meaning these things would be able to support binary data properly rather than accidentally...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using [`Iterator::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Iterator%3a%3aFile)? I suggest you abandon it precisely because of problems like this as it doesn't offer anything beyond the standard `while (<>) { ... }` interface.

Open your file with

```
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-16LE)', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;
```

and then read it with

```
my @lines;
while (my $buffer = <$fh>) {
  push @lines, $buffer;
}
```

or just

```
my @lines = <$fh>;
```

But have you considered processing the file line-by-line? It is rare that you need all of the data in memory at once.

Comment: Not sure I agree with your 1st paragraph.  My understanding is that `FB_QUIET` consumes the successfully decoded portion of the buffer.  Everything else: +1

Comment: @tjd: Thanks. I wasn't aware of how that worked. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, generally I'd use a filehandle, but this is tying into a system that can fetch files from various locations and present them as iterators. The iterators returns lines, but don't know about encoding. I want to be able to use UTF16 files with them.Reading the contents into an array is just an example (actually, this thing is itself an iterator that decodes CSVs and returns hashrefs, but that's irrelevant :))

Comment: Then you might try setting a *default* open mode with `use open qw/ :std :encoding(UTF-16LE) /` or are your encodings also mixed? Are you in fact using `Iterator::File`, or could there be any number of different iterator classes, all with a `next` method?

Comment: @Borodin, isn't `use open` lexically scoped?

Comment: As I say, this is part of a larger system that works with iterators (it does stuff like access remote files and various other things), so falling back to filehandles will lose a lot of existing functionality. Looking at it I think I'll have to go rework them so there's another buffer layer above the UTF-16 decoding, just to get everything back to being line-based.

Comment: @Borodin, It's lexically scoped, and it wouldn't help anyway because of where the :crlf is placed on Windows machines. You actually need `'<:raw:encoding(UTF-16LE):crlf'` or `'<:raw:encoding(UTF-16LE)'` depending on whether you want to keep the CR or not.

Comment: @cjm: Yes, you are right. a recent comment here suggested that it wasn't, and I took it as true without checking. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, it really looks like you need to fix your iterator classes so that the data is decoded correctly when the resource is opened, rather than trying to patch the result after UTF-16 has been misread as a byte encoding